# State not updating in React/Rudux Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I have searched high and low for a solution to this problem and haven't found an answer. Any closely related questions end up solving the problem by fixing state mutation issues which I am pert near positive I don't have. Also, I have done similar things a few times before that have worked just fine, and referring back to the code for those projects shown no significant differences with what I'm doing here.

I have a small React app that will get bigger over time so I'm using Redux for state management. Currently I have a main App component that will eventually be the parent for my routing, but for now I just have a single component inside of it that will be a Login page. The current thing I am trying to accomplish is simply to change the value of `showCreateAccountFlyout` from `false` to `true` when I click `ButtonPseudoAnchor` in the Login page.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

/* ---- Routes ----- */
import Login from './scenes/Login';

/* ----- Redux Store ----- */
import store from './redux/configureStore';

/* ----- Styles ----- */
import reset from './globalStyles/reset.scss';

export default class App extends React.Component<void> {  
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import ButtonBasic from '../components/buttons/ButtonBasic';
import ButtonRow from '../components/buttons/ButtonRow';
import ButtonPseudoAnchor from '../components/buttons/ButtonPseudoAnchor';
import FlyoutFullScreen from '../components/containers/FlyoutFullScreen';
import FormElementBasic from '../components/formElements/FormElementBasic';
import PageBasic from '../components/containers/PageBasic';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleCreateAccountFlyout } from '../redux/actions/loginActions';

/* ----- Styles ----- */
import loginStyles from './loginStyles.scss';


class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler() {
this.props.toggleCreateAccountFlyoutHandler(!this.props.showCreateAccountFlyout);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PageBasic contextualModifier="loginPage">
        <div className={loginStyles.loginContainer}>
          <div className={loginStyles.baphometLogo}>baphomet</div>
          <FormElementBasic
            type="text"
            placeholderText="Username or Email"
          />
          <FormElementBasic
            type="password"
            placeholderText="Password"
          />
          <ButtonRow rowAlignment="center">
            <ButtonBasic
              buttonText="Enter"
              buttonType="primary"
            />
          </ButtonRow>
          <ButtonPseudoAnchor onClickFunc={this.onClickHandler}>Create Account</ButtonPseudoAnchor>
        </div>
        <FlyoutFullScreen showFlyout={this.props.showCreateAccountFlyout} />
      </PageBasic>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    showCreateAccountFlyout: state.loginReducer.showCreateAccountFlyout
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    toggleCreateAccountFlyoutHandler: showCreateAccountFlyout =>
      dispatch(toggleCreateAccountFlyout(showCreateAccountFlyout))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

**loginActions.js**

```
export const TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT = 'TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT';

export function toggleCreateAccountFlyout(showCreateAccountFlyout) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT,
    payload: showCreateAccountFlyout
  }
}
```

**loginReducer.js**

```
import { TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT } from '../actions/loginActions';

export default function loginReducer(state = {
  showCreateAccountFlyout: false
}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT:
      return { ...state, showCreateAccountFlyout: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import loginReducer from './loginReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware: Function = applyMiddleware(thunk);

export default createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

As I step through everything, the new `showCreateAccountFlyout` value is being passed along, it just appears to never get passed back to the `Login` component from the reducer. Maybe there is something super simple I'm missing? I dunno.

Comment: inside you `TOGGLE_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FLYOUT` you are return `action.payload `instead you should be returning `action.payload.data`?

Comment: @Aaqib There is no `data` object inside of `action.payload`. It would just return `undefined`.